# Soap: Header.....problemas

Tags: android, webservice, soap

Tengo problemas con una App en el Web Service que se consumía exitosamente. El detalle fué cuando se le agrego seguridad al Web Service, para esto se le añadió un header.

¿Quien me puede orientar cual podría ser el detalle? 
¡Al parecer recibo respuesta del Web Service!

Mi asyntask:

```
public class WSLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

//Aqui van mis variables string Namespacer etc etc etc///

    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;
    String user = edtuserid.getText().toString();
    String pass = edtpass.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(Login.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(isSuccess) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,LibroCampo.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);

        request.addProperty("sID", user);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        Element[] headvalues = new Element[1];
        headvalues[0] = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, tagCredecial);

        Element tagUser = new Element().createElement(null, tagUSER);
        tagUser.addChild(Node.TEXT, valUSER);
        headvalues[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, tagUser);

        Element tagPass = new Element().createElement(null, tagPASS);
        tagPass.addChild(Node.TEXT, valPASS);
        headvalues[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, tagPass);

        envelope.headerOut = headvalues;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transporte.debug = true;


        if(user.trim().equals("") || pass.trim().equals("")) {
            z = "Usuario o Contraseña vacios";
        } else {
            try {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                if ( user.equals(result.getProperty(0).toString()) &&  pass.equals(result.getProperty(2).toString())) {
                    z = "Bienvenido " + result.getProperty(1);
                    isSuccess=true;
                    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.delete("tb_user_local",null, null);
                    ContentValues sEmp = new ContentValues();
                    sEmp.put("sIdUsuario", result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    sEmp.put("sUsuario", result.getProperty(1).toString());
                    sEmp.put("sPw", result.getProperty(2).toString());
                    sEmp.put("sIdAlmacen", Integer.valueOf(result.getProperty(3).toString()));
                    sEmp.put("bVerTodos", Boolean.valueOf(result.getProperty(4).toString()));
                    sEmp.put("bStatus", Boolean.valueOf(result.getProperty(5).toString()));
                    db.insert("tb_user_local",null, sEmp);
                }else{
                    z = "Acceso denegado";
                    isSuccess=false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "Acceso denegado" + e;
                Log.i("", "" + e);
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

EL error que marcar:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'El servidor no puede procesar la solicitud. ---> El mensaje de entrada no cumple el requisito R1012 de Simple SOAP Binding Profile 1.0.: UN MENSAJE DEBE serializar el sobre con codificación de caracteres UTF-8 o UTF-16.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@6c112e8
```

Comment: Mark, que header se agregó?

Comment: <soap:Header>
    <tagCredencial xmlns="namespacer">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <UserPassword>string</UserPassword>
    </tagCredencial>
  </soap:Header>

Comment: ya encontre (Son los prefijos) el error pero encuentro como, la unica forma es editar la clase que envuelve mi peticion, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno amigos despues de horas y dias de darme de a topes la solucion estaba tan sencilla que mejor como dicen aca en mi pueblo ni llorar es bueno... pero ahi les va la respuesta:

El problema radicaba en que en el objeto SoapSerializationEnvelope no añadia el charset UTF-8, y les pongo la solucion para les ayude en sus proyectos y apliaciones, en hora buena:

1. Primero que nada la dependicia del Ksoap2-android-assambly-3.4.0-jar-whith-dependencies, es la que me funciono, ya que estaba usando una version anterior que no admitia en la funcion la opcion que deseaba; tranquilos explicare en los siguientes puntos, como construir correctamente los objetos y como llenar correctamente la funcion.
2. Si ven esta respuesta ya se dieron cuenta de como construir o armar el objeto SoapSerializationEnvelope el cual se encarga de de crear la estructura de la peticion y la clase que se encarga de crearlo, con sus respectivas opciones de configuracion:

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           envelope.implicitTypes = true; 
           envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
           envelope.dotNet = true;
           envelope.headerOut = header;
3. Ademas de esta estructura se añaden otros valores que identifican el tipo de documeto, el metodo de envio, el CHARTSET(es este parametro que medio varios dolores de cabeza), en teoria (desconosco mucho de android, apenas llevo dos meses desarrollando en esta plataforma) las clases(padres e hijos) que se encargan de eso es le pongo el codigo:

   HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
4. Hasta este punto todo funcionaba correctamente, esta parte es opcional( a menos si manejas mas seguridad a la hora de hacer peticiones al Web Service) en mi caso no, añado el siguiente codigo y el parametro que me falta añadir:

   List headerPropertieList = new ArrayList();
    headerPropertieList.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
5. para luego utilizar en el metodo Call de objeto HttpTransportSE, y queda de la siguiente manera:

   transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerPropertieList);
   ///todo su codigo o metodos o clases en fin todo lo que se les ocurra :D
6. Y Presto todo funciona(al menos para mi exitosamente).

Espero que ayude no lo se todo, pero estamos en el proceso de aprendizaje esta fue mi experiencia

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error:

> El mensaje de entrada no cumple el requisito R1012 de Simple SOAP
>   Binding Profile 1.0.: UN MENSAJE DEBE serializar el sobre con
>   codificación de caracteres UTF-8 o UTF-16.'

agrega la propiedad `encodingStyle = "UTF-8"` a tu request:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.encodingStyle = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: gracias por responder, ya probe sigue saliendo el mismo error....

Comment: probaste usando encoding UTF-16?

Comment: si..... :S..... tengo una corazonada que puede ser el web service que no esta procesando correctamente la recepcion de los datos en teroria estoy creando correctamente los elements

Comment: ahi se me fue la "R"

Comment: ya encontre el error: en la peticion el objeto SoapSeerializationEnvelope no agrega la etiqueta que identifica la peticion como un XML

Comment: Agrega tu respuesta Mark para que ayude a otros.

Comment: bueno... no es una respuesta si no la base del problema es que aunque agregrege el tag de indentificacion:  transporte.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");

Comment: son los prefijos que llevan las etiquetas esas no he podido cambiar alguien sabe????